# TaskCanceledException always occurs when a httpClient.GetAsync() call is made on some Lumia 520s (but not my own)

Tags: c#, exception, windows-phone-8, httpclient, asynchttpclient

I have a method that requests the weather via a web service. This works absolutely fine on my Lumia 520 (on Windows Phone 8), but a couple of users on Lumia 520 (also running Windows Phone 8) have reported it never works. I got one on the beta, made the beta output the exception, and I was told it's a TaskCanceledException exception that always occurs. This is the code for the method:

```
public async Task<string> getWeatherForCurrentLocation( bool isViaSettings = true )
{
    try
    {
    // Base url is to the web service with the API key and longitude/latitude provided.
    var baseURL = string.Format(URL_FULL_WEATHER, APIKEY, this.Locations[0].Latitude, this.Locations[0].Longitude);

    // Create an HttpClient instance
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();

    try
    {
        httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);

        // Send a request asynchronously continue when complete
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(baseURL);

        // Check that response was successful or throw exception
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        // Read response asynchronously
        string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        // Deserialise response into a new ResponseCity object
        try
        {
            Location = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseCity>(responseString);


            // rest of code
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return "fail";
        }
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException t)
    {
        return "fail";
    }
}
catch (HttpRequestException e)
{
    return "fail";
}

return "success";
}
```

I've set a timeout to ensure if the weather isn't successfully returned within 20 seconds, that an error prompt appears.

Has anyone got any idea why this could be?

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

UPDATE:

I got a problematic Lumia 520 user on my beta, and can confirm that the problem is the url is returning a 404 for him. This is a "https" url. Even when he tries to open the link via IE, nothing shows. It is worth repeating that this URL definitely works. The server is not my own; it's forecast.io's.

Comment: Where does the exception occur? Set the debugger to break on all exceptions.

Comment: The TaskCanceledException is the one that is caught.

Comment: If you mean at what line does the exception occur, I can't say yet cause I've not got access to the phone currently to debug and won't for a few weeks unfortunately.

Comment: How long does it take until that exception happens? Is that URL reachable?

Comment: The URL is 100% reachable, works absolutely fine on my 1020. Timed out before on 10 seconds, so increased it to 20 and still timing out.

Comment: Are you calling Wait or Result anywhere? Waiting on any task somewhere?

Comment: I'm awaiting GetAsync and ReadAsStringAsync as you can see. Otherwise no.

Comment: Make sure you're awaiting your getWeatherForCurrentLocation() function from where you're calling it from. When you call await within a task, the parent function will continue if it's not awaited which could be causing an issue.
string str = await getWeatherAsync();

Comment: Will double-check. But if that's the case, should it not result in this exception to occur all the time, as opposed to 100% of the time on one person's 520 and never on someone else's?

Comment: Yep, the method call is awaited: string status = await getWeatherForCurrentLocation();

Comment: Updated original post with a new finding. For people having problems, they are getting a 404 when the request is made, most likely cause it's a https request.